# I have a problem when I use tikz package with Sage

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, sagetex

I used Sage 8.0 to get crystal graph :

```
$ sage: B = crystals.Tableaux(['A',2], shape=[2,1])

$ sage: latex(B)
```

and then I got the latex code:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{cv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv0}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv1}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv2}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv3}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv4}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv5}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv6}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv7}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1v2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2v5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv3v4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv4v6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv5v7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv6v7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
%
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv0,fill=cfv0,text=clv0,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=1.7676cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv1,fill=cfv1,text=clv1,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{2}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=0.246cm,y=1.2369cm]{v1}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv2,fill=cfv2,text=clv2,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{3}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=0.0cm,y=3.2539cm]{v2}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv3,fill=cfv3,text=clv3,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{3}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=3.7442cm,y=0.1936cm]{v3}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv4,fill=cfv4,text=clv4,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{2}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{3}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=5.0cm,y=1.7288cm]{v4}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv5,fill=cfv5,text=clv5,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{3}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{3}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=1.2019cm,y=4.8424cm]{v5}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv6,fill=cfv6,text=clv6,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{2}&\lr{2}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{3}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=4.7553cm,y=3.7377cm]{v6}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv7,fill=cfv7,text=clv7,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}
\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{2}&\lr{3}\\\cline{1-2}
\lr{3}\\\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$}
}$},x=3.2001cm,y=5.0cm]{v7}
%
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv0v1,},](v0)(v1)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv0v3,},](v0)(v3)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv1v2,},](v1)(v2)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv2v5,},](v2)(v5)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv3v4,},](v3)(v4)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv4v6,},](v4)(v6)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv5v7,},](v5)(v7)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={post, bend right,color=cv6v7,},](v6)(v7)
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and then by using TexLive 2017, I compiled it, but there are errors :

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/private/tmp/.texpadtmp a2rho.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a2rho.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paper/paper.cls
Document Class: paper 2008/05/30 1.0l LaTeX document class (wm).
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dot2texi/dot2texi.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))

Package dot2texi Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(dot2texi)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..

) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-graph/tkz-graph.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex))) (/private/tmp/.texpadtmp/a2rho.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
./a2rho.tex:51: Illegal parameter number in definition of \cmdGR@vertex@L.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.51 }$},x=1.7676cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}

./a2rho.tex:51: Illegal parameter number in definition of \cmdGR@vertex@L.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.51 }$},x=1.7676cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}

./a2rho.tex:51: Undefined control sequence.
\cmdGR@vertex@L ->\hbox {${\def \lr 
                                    ##1{\multicolumn {1}{|@{\hspace {.6ex}}c...
l.51 }$},x=1.7676cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}

./a2rho.tex:51: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@gtempa.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.51 }$},x=1.7676cm,y=0.0cm]{v0}

./a2rho.tex:52: Undefined control sequence.
l.52 ...e=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr
                                                  #1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hsp...
./a2rho.tex:52: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@gtempa.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.52 ...circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1
                                                  {\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspac...
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 52.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> a2rho.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> a2rho.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /private/tmp/.texpadtmp/a2rho.log.
```

I try to solve this problem, but I cannot do anything.

Comment: You might have more luck asking your question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support. Certainly if you want to get the problem fixed in later releases of sage this is where you should ask.

Comment: This question has come up already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342983/on-drawing-a-crystal-graph-i-have-a-trouble-illegal-parameter-number-in-defi). See the comment by Piet van Oostrum. It is a Sage issue and not a LaTeX issue.

Comment: @WIN Could you maybe give small MWE, which reproduces the problem?