# Complicated vertex labels with tkz-graph

Tags: arrays, tkz-graph

This is a follow-up to [On drawing a crystal graph, I have a trouble: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \cmdGR@vertex@L](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342983/on-drawing-a-crystal-graph-i-have-a-trouble-illegal-parameter-number-in-defi): I would like to use `tkz-graph` and label a vertex with something a little complicated: a diagram of the form

```
1 1
2
```

with boxes around the numbers, like this:
[image: Young tableau]

Sample LaTeX code to produce this diagram:

```
{\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}\raisebox{-.6ex}
{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}\lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}\end{array}$}}
```

If I use this as quoted below, I get an error as in the cited question:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \cmdGR@vertex@L.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.51 ...end{array}$}}$},x=5cm,y=1cm]{v0}
```

As noted in the cited question, this arises in code from Sage and in particular from a bug in Sage, and I would like to fix that bug by improving the LaTeX code. The "sample" code above is what Sage currently uses, so that's what I would like to replace.

A sample file that produces the error, and if you remove the offending `tikzpicture`, you can see what the vertex label should look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\Vertex[L=\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}\raisebox{-.6ex}{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}
\lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}\end{array}$}}$},x=5cm,y=1cm]{v0}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

The desired vertex label:
\[
\hbox{${\def\lr#1{\multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{.6ex}}c@{\hspace{.6ex}}|}{\raisebox{-.3ex}{$#1$}}}\raisebox{-.6ex}
{$\begin{array}[b]{*{2}c}\cline{1-2}\lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}\lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}\end{array}$}}$}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is where `lr` is defined. It needs to be defined *outside* of the `\Vertex` command. In there, you cannot use `\multicolumn{...}{...}{...}`. There are multiple ways to overcome this:

- The cleanest approach: don't use `multicolumn` but add the vertical lines in the array arguments using `{*n{|c}|}`, where `n` is the number of columns in the array. Also, `\lr{...}` will be redundant but it is there in case you wanted to customize the look of each cell

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[VertexStyle/.append style={draw=none, fill=none}]
        \def\lr#1{#1}
        \Vertex[L=
        $\begin{array}{*2{|c}|}\cline{1-2}
        \lr{A}&\lr{B}\\\cline{1-2}
        \lr{C}\\\cline{1-1}
        \end{array}$
        ,x=5cm,y=1cm]{v0}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: First approach output]

- The second approach is similar to the first one but includes some of the other commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[VertexStyle/.append style={draw=none, fill=none}]
        \def\lr#1{#1}
        \Vertex[L=
        \hbox{
        ${
        \raisebox{-.6ex}{
        $\begin{array}[b]{*{2}{|c}|}\cline{1-2}
        \lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}
        \lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}
        \end{array}
        $}}$
        },x=5cm,y=1cm]{v0}
        %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second approach output]

- **BONUS:** A more compact version of the first approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\newcommand{\myVertex}[5]{%
\Vertex[L=$\begin{array}{*#2{|c}|}#1\end{array}$,x=#3,y=#4]{#5}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[VertexStyle/.append style={draw=blue, fill=none}]
        \myVertex{
        \cline{1-3}
        A&B&C\\\cline{1-3}
        D&E\\\cline{1-2}
        F\\\cline{1-1}
        }{3}{1cm}{1cm}{v0}

        \myVertex{
        \cline{1-3}
        1&2&3\\\cline{1-3}
        4&5\\\cline{1-2}
        6\\\cline{1-1}
        }{3}{3cm}{1cm}{v1}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bonus approach output]

---

## Original Answer:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\lr#1{#1}%keep it aligned with the code generated and for cell customization
        %
        \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={draw=none}}
        \Vertex[L=\hbox{
        $
        \begin{array}{|c|c|}\cline{1-2}
        \lr{1}&\lr{1}\\\cline{1-2}
        \lr{2}\\\cline{1-1}
        \end{array}
        $}
        ,x=5cm,y=1cm]{v0}
        %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me and gives me some ideas for fixing it in Sage.